# Passing parameters to promise's callback in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, callback

I am trying to figure out is there is any way to pass in an index argument to a promise's callback function. For instance.

```
serviceCall.$promise.then(function(object){
    $scope.object = object;
});
```

Now I want to pass in an array index parameter as

```
serviceCall.$promise.then(function(object,i){
    $scope.object[i] = something;
});
```

Can this be done? Please let me know.

Here is the code below

```
StudyService.studies.get({id:    
$routeParams.studyIdentifier}).$promise.then(function(study) {
$scope.study = study;
for(var i=0;i<study.cases.length;i++){
  StudyService.executionsteps.get({id:   
  $routeParams.studyIdentifier,caseId:study.cases[i].id})
      .$promise.then(function(executionSteps,i){
      $scope.study.cases[i].executionSteps = executionSteps;
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Object is just another Class called Study that contains inside it a list of cases, each of these cases has a list of steps. So I need to be able to index inside of the callback function.

Comment: where do you get `i` from?

Comment: Please see the code I just added in my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can promises have multiple arguments to onFulfilled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773920/can-promises-have-multiple-arguments-to-onfulfilled)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) for that.

for example, in your code, use something like:

```
function callbackCreator(i) {
  return function(executionSteps) {
    $scope.study.cases[i].executionSteps = executionSteps;
  }
}
StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier})
  .$promise.then(function(study) {
    $scope.study = study;
    for(var i=0;i<study.cases.length;i++) {
      var callback = callbackCreator(i);
      StudyService.executionsteps.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier,caseId:study.cases[i].id})
        .$promise.then(callback);
   }
});
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/939206/187812) elaborates a bit on defining a function that returns a callback that can use additional data.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar and I put a promise on each and then used `$q.all()` on the array of promises like:

```
$q.all( arrayOfPromises )
.then(function(results) {
   console.log(results[0], results[1], results[2]);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't give the opportunity to pass the key through to the .then() function. You have just hardcoded the keys in the JS