# Passing parameters to promise's success callback in angularjs $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I realize this is a very similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963151/passing-parameters-to-promises-callback-in-angularjs). But I'm still unclear on how to do it in my situation. Just need some help with a successful callback.

This is what works:

```
function getStuff(accountNumber) {
    var logMessage = 'POST GetStuff';

    return $http.post(GetStuff, { custId: accountNumber })
        .then(log);
}

function log(response) {
    logger.debug(response);
    return response;
}
```

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
function getStuff(accountNumber) {
    var logMessage = 'POST GetStuff';

    return $http.post(GetStuff, { custId: accountNumber })
        .then(log(response, logMessage);
}

function log(response, logMessage) {
    logger.debug(logMessage, response);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function getStuff(accountNumber) {
    var logMessage = 'POST GetStuff';

    return $http.post(GetStuff, { custId: accountNumber })
        .then(
           function success(response) {
               return log(response, logMessage);
           }
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, I will use this. It makes the most sense.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your preference/requirements you could do a few things. I normally write promise callbacks like this, so you could do:

```
.then(function success(response){
  return log(response, logMessage);
});
```

or, depending on how you feel about this way (i know some people don't like it, i try to avoid unless absoluley nessesary)

```
.then(log.bind(null, response, logMessage));
```

Do either of these work for you?

Comment: Thanks @Shan, Rohit answered first and the same as your first suggestion, so I took his answer. I couldn't get bind to work and it does look funny, but your first suggestion is good.

Answer (score 0):

See if it can help you:

```
function getStuff(accountNumber) {
  var logMessage = 'POST GetStuff';
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  return $http.post(GetStuff, { custId: accountNumber })
   .success(function(response){
      deferred.resolve(response);
      log(response, logMessage);
   }).error(function(){
      deferred.reject();
   })     
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali, just trying to use the then method.

Comment: BTW, `success` and `error` methods are deprecated in favour of `then()` method.

Comment: thanks for remind but it is for jQuery and not for jqlite which Angular is using internally, see this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ixmLu9NPm8k