# How to pass additional variables into a Firebase promise's callback in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

We are trying to pass additional variables into a Firebase .ON promise's callback.
We have looked at dozens of posts on SO describing how to pass static variables into callback functions for .ON methods - but each version is throwing a data.val() undefined error for us.

Here is sample code. We want to pass in a value for i:

```
var path = firebase.database().ref(our_firebase_data_url);
var fx = function fx_call(data) {
    value = data.val();
    console.log("Here is your passed parameter: " + i); // we want this defined 
};
path.on('value', fx);
```

We thought we might be able to do something like this but we are unable to get variations on this to work:

```
fx_call(data,i) { 
     value = data.val();
     i = i.val(); 
};
```

Alternatively, it looked like we could pass in our values via a .bind statement:

```
fx_call(data,i) { 
     value = data.val();
     i = i.val(); 
}.bind(this, i) # we also tried .bind(null,i) and .bind(i)
```

But every approach we have tried from multiple SO posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711211/bind-variables-to-callback-function),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925138/bind-more-arguments-of-an-already-bound-function-in-javascript),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465183/passing-parameters-to-promises-success-callback-in-angularjs-q) and others) resulted in a data.val() undefined error for us.

How can we pass in additional variable parameters to our promise's callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found an answer outside of SO, so we are asking and answering to add it here.

You can pass variables into functions including Firebase promise callbacks using a .bind statement formatted this way:

```
 fx_call(data,i) { 
         value = data.val();
         i = this.i; # this is how you access the value from the bind
         j = this.j; 
 }.bind( {i: i, j: 10} ) # this is how you pass variables into the callback function...this.i will be whatever value the scope of i was at the time the function was created...this.j in this case will be 10
```

Comment: you may as well have `var i=5, j=10` at the top of the function - I must've missed the point of the question

Comment: @JaromandaX The integers were just placeholders for where actual variables would go. Answer revised to show that with i.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :) you can also do it like this

path.on('value',function(data){
...something
}.bind({something}));