# Asyncawait.js multiple arguments in callback

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm getting more and more confortable with the [asyncawait](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) library.

If I'm correct, this:

```
var doSth = async function() {
  var asyncResult = await promiseReturningFunction();
  subFunction(asyncResult);
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
var doSth = function() {
  promiseReturningFunction().then(function(asyncResult) {
    subFunction(asyncResult);
  });
};
```

But what if the callback has two arguments `.then(function(asyncResult1, asyncResult2) {})`?

In some other languages, I'd write:

```
  var asyncResult1, asyncResult2 = await promiseReturningFunction();
```

but I can't do this in JS, can I? Does await returns an array? The first argument?

Comment: The asyncawait library and the upcoming `async/await` are two different things. They may work in a very similar way, but you should clarify which one you are talking about. Even though you are linking to the library, your example doesn't seem to use the library.

Comment: Are you using the experimental async/await transpiler, or that fiber-based library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I can't do this in JS, can I?

No, you can't. Promises fulfill with only a single value.

JavaScript doesn't have tuples, but you can use an array for that. With destructuring, you can make it look almost like in those other languages:

```
async function promiseReturningFunction() {
    await …;
    …
    return [result1, result2];
}

// elsewhere (in an async function):
var [asyncResult1, asyncResult2] = await promiseReturningFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the `destructuring` on a bunch of promises like that:

```
var [r1, r2, r3] = await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);
```

or

```
var promises = [p1(), p2(), p3()];
$q.all(promises)
  .then(function ([p1Result, p2Result, p3Result]) {
      // ...
  });
```

So you will have:

```
async function doSth() {
    var [asyncResult1, asyncResult1] = await promiseReturningFunction();
    var asyncLastResult = await subFunction(asyncResult1);

    return asyncLastResult;
}

doSth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises can only pass one argument to the fulfillment callback. [As Benjamin Gruenbaum writes:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776850/1105858)

> [...] Just the first parameter will be treated as resolution value in the promise constructor. You can resolve with a composite value like an object or array.

([Here is the section in the Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-27))

So your case with two arguments doesn't occur in JavaScript (at least not with standard promise implementations). Just use an array or an object (depending on your data structure).