# Getting no value in second function of promise

Tags: node.js, promise

Here are the codes to promise that i have written

```
module.exports['getTemplate'] = (object)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    var content = cache.get(object['template']);
    if(content == null){
      reader("./templates/"+object['template'],'utf8',function(err,data){
        if(err){
          reject(err);
        } else{
          cache.put(object['template'],data);
          fullfill(data,object['data']);
          1) ~~~~>  console.log(object['data']);
        }
      });
    }else{
      fullfill(content,object['data']);
    }
  });
}

module.exports['render'] = (template,context)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    2 ~~~~~~> console.log(context);
    try{
      var html = mustache.render(template,context);
      fullfill(html,context);
    }catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

and i am calling them using `promise` in main app like

```
helper['parseJson'](item)
    .then(helper['getTemplate'])
    .then(helper['render'])
```

The problem is that the value is set in first `console.log` but becomes `undefined` in second function although the value of template is coming all fine. Can someone please explain to me where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Promises can be fulfilled with only one argument (the rest is ignored) ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773920/can-promises-have-multiple-arguments-to-onfulfilled

Comment: If you want to resolve with more than value from a promise, you have to put the values into an object and then resolve with that object.  `resolve()` only takes one argument.

Comment: @MarcoGabrielGodoyLema thanks a lot. Thats something new for me today :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises can be fulfilled with only one value. You'll need to resolve an object or array if you need multiple values:

```
module.exports['getTemplate'] = (object)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    var content = cache.get(object['template']);
    if(content == null){
      reader("./templates/"+object['template'],'utf8',function(err,data){
        if(err){
          reject(err);
        } else{
          cache.put(object['template'],data);

          fullfill({template: data, context: object['data']});
          1) ~~~~>  console.log(object['data']);
        }
      });
    }else{
      fullfill(content,object['data']);
    }
  });
}

module.exports['render'] = (data)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    2 ~~~~~~> console.log(data.context);
    try{
      var html = mustache.render(data.template,data.context);
      fullfill({html: html, context: data.context});
    }catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve