# Why Promise design for only returns one result?

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('result1', 'resolve2');
}).then((result1, result2) => {
    console.info(result1, result2);
});
```

Why Promise returns only one result in JavaScript like in the above code?

I'm sorry for my unclearly describe. I'm know how to return an object or an array value in resolve. **I'm just curious *why* Promise design to return only on result.**

Comment: Resolve only takes one argument & that is the returned data. Just resolve an array with your two results - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: because it take only one parameter, use an array : `resolve('result1', 'resolve2');`  ... `then((array)=>{result1 = array[0];result2=array[1];});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can promises have multiple arguments to onFulfilled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773920/can-promises-have-multiple-arguments-to-onfulfilled)

Comment: I'm just curious **why** Promise design to return only one result.

Answer (score 1):

Promise always returns one value. But you can do a trick to get as two using [**Array destructing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Pass an array or object to the `resolve/reject` function and using destructing get them as separate variables.

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve( ['result1', 'resolve2'] );
}).then( ( [result1, result2] ) => {
    console.info(result1, result2);
});
```