# Continue after array of promises has completed either with success or fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, es6-promise

I want to proceed when all promises are either resolved or rejected and display the string "##### should be  final call  ####" at the end.

---

**TL;DR;**

I forgot to return the promise in the map function.

---

I am trying to use this approach:
[Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises)

What is the problem with the below code?

I would expect the `.then` handler of `Promise.all()` to be called at last, after all others.

The result variable contains an array with undefined values.

```js
console.clear();

$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "https://httpbin.org/get?";
    a = [];

    a.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.get(url + Math.random()).then((res) => resolve()).fail(() => {
            reject();
        });
    }));
    a.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.get(url + Math.random()).then((res) => resolve()).fail(() => {
            reject();
        });
    }));

    var mr = getPromise();

    function getPromise() {
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                reject();

            }, 1000);
        });
        return promise;
    }

    a.push(mr);

    a.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.get(url + Math.random()).then((res) => resolve()).fail(() => {
            reject();
        });
    }));

    a.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.get(url + Math.random()).then((res) => resolve()).fail(() => {
            reject();
        });
    }));

    Promise.all(a.map((p) => {
            p.catch((e) => {
                console.log("failed promise catch");
            });
        }))
        .then((results) => {
            console.log("##### should be  final call  ####");
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log("final catch block executed");
        });


}); // ready end
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works as expected in NodeJS.  Weird that it fails in the browser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Simply use

```
function getPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.setTimeout(reject, 1000);
  });
}
const url = "https://httpbin.org/get?";
a = [
  Promise.resolve($.get(url+ Math.random())),
  Promise.resolve($.get(url+ Math.random())),
  getPromise(),
  Promise.resolve($.get(url+ Math.random())),
  Promise.resolve($.get(url+ Math.random()))
];
```

Then your problem is just that you forgot to `return` the chained promise (with the handled rejections) from the `map` callback, so you had called `Promise.all` on an array of `undefined`s which immediately fulfilled. Change it to:

```
Promise.all(a.map(p => {
  return p.catch(e => { console.log("failed promise catch"); });
//^^^^^^
}))
.then(results => {
  console.log("##### should be  final call  ####");
}, e => {
  console.log("final catch block executed");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. But I have one further question regarding `Promise.resolve(..)`. What if the `.then` handler of the `$.get` request relies on data from the currently executing function context. In `Promise.then(..)` I only get the result of the request...

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115/2581562) a highly upvoted answer, which uses this anti pattern to promisify native xhr requests. Actually all the answers use this anti pattern.

Comment: @Legends What do you mean by "currently executing context"? There's nothing that couldn't be done with `then` as well.

Comment: @Legends No, it's not an antipattern to use the `Promise` constructor for promisifying anything. It is an antipattern to try to promisify a thing that already returns a promise (like `$.ajax` or `fetch`), or to write your own (but worse) `then` pattern.

Comment: Here is also the answer to my first question in this comment thread regarding additional context parameters when using `Promise.resolve`
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776850/2581562](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776850/2581562)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return promise into map. You promised array of undefined which is resolved immediately.

```js
console.clear();

$(document).ready(function(){

function getPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(reject, 1000));
}

function getRandomUrl() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => $.get(url+ Math.random()).done(resolve).fail(reject));
}

var url= "https://httpbin.org/get?";
a = [];

a.push(getRandomUrl());
a.push(getRandomUrl());
a.push(getPromise());
a.push(getRandomUrl());
a.push(getRandomUrl());

Promise.all(a.map(p => {
    return p.catch(console.log);   
  }))
  .then((results) => {
    console.log("##### should be  final call  ####");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("final catch block executed");
  });


});// ready end
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```